# Copied code over to same program but not working? Slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python, spyder

Hi I'm very new to Python and have been using Spyder to process images for a report. I'm working from home and downloaded Anaconda Navigator to use Spyder.

The following code has been directly copied from my work laptop which also uses Spyder, so I don't understand why the error "slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method" keeps coming up.

```
from scipy.ndimage import interpolation
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

def normalise_image(input_img):
    norm = (input_img-np.min(input_img))/(np.max(input_img)-np.min(input_img))
    return norm

loc = 'C:/Users/Gemma/Documents/Katy College/Applications/NUFFIELD/Polarisation Data/THURSDAY/Abbypalm_thursday/'
loc1 = loc + 'Camera1/0.040.png'
loc2 = loc + 'Camera2/0.040.png'

Image1 = Image.open(loc1)
Image2 = Image.open(loc2)

Image1array = np.array(Image1, dtype=float)
Image2array = np.array(Image2, dtype=float)

# Flipped Image and Cut out last row
Image2array = np.flipud(Image2array)
Image2array = np.fliplr(Image2array)

Image2array = interpolation.rotate(Image2array,0.95)

mid_x, mid_y = Image2array.shape[0]/2, Image2array.shape[1]/2
offset_in_v = 5
Image2array = Image2array[mid_x-494/2+offset_in_v:mid_x+493/2+offset_in_v, 
mid_y-660/2:mid_y+659/2]
color = 'binary'

Image2array=normalise_image(Image2array)
Image1array=normalise_image(Image1array)

DOP = np.zeros((Image2array.shape), dtype=float)
for i in range(Image2array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(Image2array.shape[1]):
        if (Image2array[i,j] + Image1array[i,j]) == 0:
            DOP[i,j] = 0.0
        else:
            DOP[i,j] = (Image2array[i,j] - 
Image1array[i,j])/(Image2array[i,j] + Image1array[i,j])

plt.figure('Parallel')
plt.imshow(Image1array,cmap='binary')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

plt.figure('Perpendicular')
plt.imshow(Image2array,cmap='binary')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

plt.figure('DOP')
plt.imshow(DOP,cmap=color)
plt.colorbar()
plt.imsave(loc + 'DOP'+color+'.png',DOP,cmap=color)
plt.show()
```

I've put all the code in since I don't know which is most important. My supervisor dictated the code to me to write it. Spyder says the problem is with line 36: Image2array = Image2array[mid_x-494/2+offset_in_v:mid_x+493/2+offset_in_v, mid_y-660/2:mid_y+659/2]

Thank you in advance,

Katy

Answer (score 0):

I recon the problem is `Image2array = Image2array[mid_x-494/2+offset_in_v:mid_x+493/2+offset_in_v, mid_y-660/2:mid_y+659/2]` is resulting in floating point slicing indices probably because of lack of operator precedence while calculating those indices and behaviour of integer division in different versions of Python.

Image2array = Image2array[mid_x-494/2+offset_in_v:mid_x+493/2+offset_in_v, mid_y-660/2:**mid_y+659/2**]

An example is `mid_y+659/2` highlighted above where `/` has a higher precedence than `+` hence the operation will be evaluated as `mid_y+(659/2)` with `659/2` being evaluated first and it's result which is `329.5` added to `mid_y`. So even if `mid_y` is an int, you end up with and slicing index with a `.5`

I suggest adding in `()` to have your precedence order followed.

Also the behaviour of `/` has changed between Python 2 and 3 and since you copied the script from one machine that could be running a different version of Python from the one you are using, you may have to use the floor division operator `//` to drop off the floating point on integer divisions in Python 3 that was always the case with `/` in Python 2

Answer (score 0):

If you copy between machines with different python versions you might be tripped up by the change of meaning for the `/` operator.
In older pythons, `/` between integers resulted in an integer.
Younger pythons have it result in floats.
Using the `//` in younger pythons gets you the needed integer.

Try using `//` instead of `/` in that line.

```
Image2array = Image2array[mid_x-494/2+offset_in_v:mid_x+493/2+offset_in_v, 
mid_y-660/2:mid_y+659/2]
```

->

```
Image2array = Image2array[mid_x-494//2+offset_in_v:mid_x+493//2+offset_in_v, 
mid_y-660//2:mid_y+659//2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that the problem is caused by differing versions of Python, and since you are using Anaconda, you should create a new `conda` environment with the appropriate Python version. For example, if the original code is written for Python 2.7:

`conda create -n myenv python=2.7 spyder scipy numpy PIL matplotlib`

will create a new environment named `myenv` containing Python 2.7, Spyder, and the other modules that your code requires.

To use Spyder in this environment you first **activate** the environment, then run Spyder:

```
activate myenv
spyder
```

You may also be able to do this in the Navigator and/or via a Start menu shortcut, but the command line version should always work.